# <a> tag smaller than children

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to make a simple rich text editor and had problems with toolbar buttons. What I'm trying to achieve is something like this: [image: Stack overflow markdown editor], but i have very strange blue underscores between the buttons. (chrome) Can you help me?

```css
#buttons svg {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  display: inline;
}

#buttons svg path {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#buttons a {
  height: 100%;
}

body div {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
}

#toolbar {
  width: 25%;
  z-index: 9;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 3rem 0 3rem;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="toolbar">
  <span id="buttons">
        <a title="New" onclick="app.new()" href="#">
            <svg>
                <path fill="#000000" d="M13,9V3.5L18.5,9M6,2C4.89,2 4,2.89 4,4V20A2,2 0 0,0 6,22H18A2,2 0 0,0 20,20V8L14,2H6Z" ></path>
            </svg>
        </a>
        <a title="Save" onclick="app.save()" href="#">
            <svg>
                <path d="M15,9H5V5H15M12,19A3,3 0 0,1 9,16A3,3 0 0,1 12,13A3,3 0 0,1 15,16A3,3 0 0,1 12,19M17,3H5C3.89,3 3,3.9 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V7L17,3Z"></path>
            </svg>
        </a>
        <a title="Open" onclick="app.open()" href="#">
            <svg>
                <path fill="#000000" d="M19,20H4C2.89,20 2,19.1 2,18V6C2,4.89 2.89,4 4,4H10L12,6H19A2,2 0 0,1 21,8H21L4,8V18L6.14,10H23.21L20.93,18.5C20.7,19.37 19.92,20 19,20Z" ></path>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I really hope to see a solution with <svg> tag since i need the app to be in one file. If that's not possible, no worries, but i really want it to be so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `<button>` instead of `<a>` in this case, since you are not navigating to a new URL.

Read more: [Links vs. Buttons in Modern Web Applications](https://marcysutton.com/links-vs-buttons-in-modern-web-applications/)

To reset the default button style, you can for example add the following CSS:

```
button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: yeah, that's true, fixing

Answer (score 1):

Its coming from the default user agent stylesheet containing property `text-decoration` for the `<a>`, you can check it using your Chrome devtools.

[image]

You can remove it by doing..

```
#buttons a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
#buttons svg {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  display: inline;
}

#buttons svg path {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#buttons a {
  height: 100%;
}

body div {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
}

#toolbar {
  width: 25%;
  z-index: 9;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 3rem 0 3rem;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="toolbar">
  <span id="buttons">
        <a title="New" onclick="app.new()" href="#">
            <svg>
                <path fill="#000000" d="M13,9V3.5L18.5,9M6,2C4.89,2 4,2.89 4,4V20A2,2 0 0,0 6,22H18A2,2 0 0,0 20,20V8L14,2H6Z" ></path>
            </svg>
        </a>
        <a title="Save" onclick="app.save()" href="#">
            <svg>
                <path d="M15,9H5V5H15M12,19A3,3 0 0,1 9,16A3,3 0 0,1 12,13A3,3 0 0,1 15,16A3,3 0 0,1 12,19M17,3H5C3.89,3 3,3.9 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V7L17,3Z"></path>
            </svg>
        </a>
        <a title="Open" onclick="app.open()" href="#">
            <svg>
                <path fill="#000000" d="M19,20H4C2.89,20 2,19.1 2,18V6C2,4.89 2.89,4 4,4H10L12,6H19A2,2 0 0,1 21,8H21L4,8V18L6.14,10H23.21L20.93,18.5C20.7,19.37 19.92,20 19,20Z" ></path>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Docs: [`text-decoration` - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `text-decoration: none;` to the `#button a { }` selector

```css
#buttons svg {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  display: inline;
}

#buttons svg path {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#buttons a {
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body div {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
}

#toolbar {
  width: 25%;
  z-index: 9;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 3rem 0 3rem;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="toolbar">
  <span id="buttons">
        <a title="New" onclick="app.new()" href="#">
            <svg>
                <path fill="#000000" d="M13,9V3.5L18.5,9M6,2C4.89,2 4,2.89 4,4V20A2,2 0 0,0 6,22H18A2,2 0 0,0 20,20V8L14,2H6Z" ></path>
            </svg>
        </a>
        <a title="Save" onclick="app.save()" href="#">
            <svg>
                <path d="M15,9H5V5H15M12,19A3,3 0 0,1 9,16A3,3 0 0,1 12,13A3,3 0 0,1 15,16A3,3 0 0,1 12,19M17,3H5C3.89,3 3,3.9 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V7L17,3Z"></path>
            </svg>
        </a>
        <a title="Open" onclick="app.open()" href="#">
            <svg>
                <path fill="#000000" d="M19,20H4C2.89,20 2,19.1 2,18V6C2,4.89 2.89,4 4,4H10L12,6H19A2,2 0 0,1 21,8H21L4,8V18L6.14,10H23.21L20.93,18.5C20.7,19.37 19.92,20 19,20Z" ></path>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use:

```
text-decoration: none;
```

Comment: Why do you suggest `text-decoration-line: blink;`, `blink` is deprecated, and the purpose of `blink` was not to hide the line, but create an alternating animation between visible and invisible.